# Sending email with attachment of zip folder not attaching the zip folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

I am trying to attach a zip file after downloading files from the server and then sending them in an email.

Here is where i am downloading the files:

```
else if (radio[0] == "Email Statements")
            {
                // Make array of emails into List for sending in email 
                if (emails.ToString() != "")
                {
                    var allEmails = emails[0].Split(',');

                    foreach (var email in allEmails)
                    {

                        if (emailValid.IsMatch(email))
                        {
                            everyEmail.Add(email);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Json(new { success = false, message = $"* Not valid email address: {email}.\n\n * Please double check and try again." });
                        }
                        List<string> distinctFiles = allPaths
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Split(new char[] { '\\' }).Last())
                            .Select(x => x.First())
                            .ToList();
                        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                        {
                            zip.AddFiles(distinctFiles, @"\");
                            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                            zip.Save(output);
                            //return File(output.ToArray(), "application/zip");
                            DBQueries.SendEmail(everyEmail, output, fromAddress, "Client Statement Reports", "Here are your requested Client Statements", true);

                        }
```

Then the DBQueries.SendEmail function will send me here and this is where I am having trouble. How can I get my downloaded files to this function correctly?

```
public static void SendEmail(List<string> recipients, MemoryStream output, string from, string subject, string htmlMessage, bool isHtml = true)
    {
        var host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailHost"];
        
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from);

            foreach (var r in recipients)
            {
                mail.To.Add(r);
            }
            
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
            mail.Body = htmlMessage;
            //string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());

            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(host);
            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            Attachment myZip = new Attachment(output);
            mail.Attachments.Add(myZip);
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
```

Comment: Set `MemoryStream.Position` to 0 before creating the attachment. Like all streams, `MemoryStream` points to the end of the stream after each append operation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the help. My issue is trying to pass my zip file to my SendEmail function. When I am passing it i have to pass it as a MemoryStream. Then i need to change this to an array or something so that I can attach it.

Comment: Yes, and unless you set `Position` to `0`, the `Attachment` class will start reading from the end of that stream.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so i did this and now im back to the problem where the attachment is being sent but the data is not correct as there is nothing in it.